# Tkinter gets slow when resizing the window. Can I have the resize command activate when the user settles instead of activating it continuously?

Tags: python, tkinter

I have lots of images and parts that resize themselves whenever the GUI resizes.

```
self.master.bind("<Configure>", self.resize_window)
```

Here's the `self.resize_window` function:

```
def resize_window(self, event):
        if event.widget == self.master: # only run if whole window gets resized
            if self.window_width != event.width: # the root window size has been changed
                self.window_width = event.width  # update current window size
                self.update_images() # this rescales all the images using cv2.resize
```

So as the window is getting resized, `self.resize_window` runs again and again until it settles.

It makes the application really slow during this resizing period. Is there a way to only call `self.resize_window` when the resizing settles or something? Or is there any other way to speed this up?

Comment: What does `resize_window` do? By default, if you bind to a root or top-level window, the binding applies to every child. So, for example, if your `resize_window` does a computation and you have 100 child windows, it will do 100 computations. Are you checking for that, so that you're only doing the computation for the root window?

Comment: To do what @Bryan is describing requires ignoring calls to your handler where the `event.widget.master` set to something — i.e. `if event.widget.master: return`.

Comment: @BryanOakley Yes, the resize window has this statement to ensure something happens only if this is true: event.widget == self.master. I'll put some code in the edit of the post.

Comment: It's not clear that what you're doing is correct nor that you understood my comment. What I meant was that the resizing code should only run when the widget **does not** have a master, something that will only be true if widget is the root or top-level window.

Comment: @martineau so how would I change that in my code? would it be something like: `if element.widget.master is None:`

Comment: Evan:  That ought to identify the root window, although all that's really needed is `if not element.widget.master:` ("if element has no master") due to the concept of the "[truthiness](https://www.udacity.com/wiki/cs258/truthiness-in-python)" of values in Python. Also note that the resizing of all the images itself may be slow, even if you only do it once.